# Are for-loops in pandas really bad? When should I care?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, vectorization, list-comprehension

**Are `for` loops really "bad"? If not, in what situation(s) would they be better than using a more conventional "vectorized" approach?<sup>1</sup>**

I am familiar with the concept of "vectorization", and how pandas employs vectorized techniques to speed up computation. Vectorized functions broadcast operations over the entire series or DataFrame to achieve speedups much greater than conventionally iterating over the data.

However, I am quite surprised to see a lot of code (including from answers on Stack Overflow) offering solutions to problems that involve looping through data using `for` loops and list comprehensions. The documentation and API say that loops are "bad", and that one should "never" iterate over arrays, series, or DataFrames. So, how come I sometimes see users suggesting loop-based solutions?

---

<sub>1 - While it is true that the question sounds somewhat broad, the truth is that there are very specific situations when `for` loops are usually better than conventionally iterating over data. This post aims to capture this for posterity.</sub>

Comment: Related: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476924/4561887)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

TLDR; No, `for` loops are not blanket "bad", at least, not always. It is probably **more accurate to say that some vectorized operations are slower than iterating**, versus saying that iteration is faster than some vectorized operations. Knowing when and why is key to getting the most performance out of your code. In a nutshell, these are the situations where it is worth considering an alternative to vectorized pandas functions:

1. When your data is small (...depending on what you're doing),
2. When dealing with `object`/mixed dtypes
3. When using the `str`/regex accessor functions

Let's examine these situations individually.

---

#### Iteration v/s Vectorization on Small Data

Pandas follows a ["Convention Over Configuration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) approach in its API design. This means that the same API has been fitted to cater to a broad range of data and use cases.

When a pandas function is called, the following things (among others) must internally be handled by the function, to ensure working

1. Index/axis alignment
2. Handling mixed datatypes
3. Handling missing data

Almost every function will have to deal with these to varying extents, and this presents an **overhead**. The overhead is less for numeric functions (for example, [`Series.add`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/ops.py#L1371-L1388)), while it is more pronounced for string functions (for example, [`Series.str.replace`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/strings.py#L635-L669)).

[`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loops, on the other hand, are faster then you think. What's even better is [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (which create lists through `for` loops) are even faster as they are optimized iterative mechanisms for list creation.

List comprehensions follow the pattern

```
[f(x) for x in seq]
```

Where `seq` is a pandas series or DataFrame column. Or, when operating over multiple columns,

```
[f(x, y) for x, y in zip(seq1, seq2)]
```

Where `seq1` and `seq2` are columns.

**Numeric Comparison**
Consider a simple boolean indexing operation. The list comprehension method has been timed against [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) and [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). Here are the functions:

```
# Boolean indexing with Numeric value comparison.
df[df.A != df.B]                            # vectorized !=
df.query('A != B')                          # query (numexpr)
df[[x != y for x, y in zip(df.A, df.B)]]    # list comp
```

For simplicity, I have used the [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) package to run all the timeit tests in this post. The timings for the operations above are below:

[image]

The list comprehension outperforms `query` for moderately sized N, and even outperforms the vectorized not equals comparison for tiny N. Unfortunately, the list comprehension scales linearly, so it does not offer much performance gain for larger N.

> **Note**
> It is worth mentioning that much of the benefit of list comprehension come from not having to worry about the index alignment,
> but this means that if your code is dependent on indexing alignment,
> this will break. In some cases, vectorised operations over the
> underlying NumPy arrays can be considered as bringing in the "best of
> both worlds", allowing for vectorisation *without* all the unneeded overhead of the pandas functions. This means that you can rewrite the operation above as
>
> ```
> df[df.A.values != df.B.values]
> ```
>
> Which outperforms both the pandas and list comprehension equivalents:
> [image]
> NumPy vectorization is out of the scope of this post, but it is definitely worth considering, if performance matters.

**Value Counts**
Taking another example - this time, with another vanilla python construct that is *faster* than a for loop - [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). A common requirement is to compute the value counts and return the result as a dictionary. This is done with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts), [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), and `Counter`:

```
# Value Counts comparison.
ser.value_counts(sort=False).to_dict()           # value_counts
dict(zip(*np.unique(ser, return_counts=True)))   # np.unique
Counter(ser)                                     # Counter
```

[image]

The results are more pronounced, `Counter` wins out over both vectorized methods for a larger range of small N (~3500).

> **Note**
> More trivia (courtesy @user2357112). The `Counter` is implemented with a [C
> accelerator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L2249-L2354),
> so while it still has to work with python objects instead of the
> underlying C datatypes, it is still faster than a `for` loop. Python
> power!

Of course, the take away from here is that the performance depends on your data and use case. The point of these examples is to convince you not to rule out these solutions as legitimate options. If these still don't give you the performance you need, there is always [cython](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#cython-writing-c-extensions-for-pandas) and [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). Let's add this test into the mix.

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def get_mask(x, y):
    result = [False] * len(x)
    for i in prange(len(x)):
        result[i] = x[i] != y[i]
    
    return np.array(result)

df[get_mask(df.A.values, df.B.values)] # numba
```

[image]

Numba offers JIT compilation of loopy python code to very powerful vectorized code. Understanding how to make numba work involves a learning curve.

---

#### Operations with Mixed/`object` dtypes

**String-based Comparison**
Revisiting the filtering example from the first section, what if the columns being compared are strings? Consider the same 3 functions above, but with the input DataFrame cast to string.

```
# Boolean indexing with string value comparison.
df[df.A != df.B]                            # vectorized !=
df.query('A != B')                          # query (numexpr)
df[[x != y for x, y in zip(df.A, df.B)]]    # list comp
```

[image]

So, what changed? The thing to note here is that **string operations are inherently difficult to vectorize.** Pandas treats strings as objects, and all operations on objects fall back to a slow, loopy implementation.

Now, because this loopy implementation is surrounded by all the overhead mentioned above, there is a constant magnitude difference between these solutions, even though they scale the same.

When it comes to operations on mutable/complex objects, there is no comparison. List comprehension outperforms all operations involving dicts and lists.

**Accessing Dictionary Value(s) by Key**
Here are timings for two operations that extract a value from a column of dictionaries: `map` and the list comprehension. The setup is in the Appendix, under the heading "Code Snippets".

```
# Dictionary value extraction.
ser.map(operator.itemgetter('value'))     # map
pd.Series([x.get('value') for x in ser])  # list comprehension
```

[image]

**Positional List Indexing**
Timings for 3 operations that extract the 0th element from a list of columns (handling exceptions), [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map), [`str.get` accessor method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html), and the list comprehension:

```py
# List positional indexing. 
def get_0th(lst):
    try:
        return lst[0]
    # Handle empty lists and NaNs gracefully.
    except (IndexError, TypeError):
        return np.nan
```

```
ser.map(get_0th)                                          # map
ser.str[0]                                                # str accessor
pd.Series([x[0] if len(x) > 0 else np.nan for x in ser])  # list comp
pd.Series([get_0th(x) for x in ser])                      # list comp safe
```

> **Note**
> If the index matters, you would want to do:
>
> ```
> pd.Series([...], index=ser.index)
> ```
>
> When reconstructing the series.

[image]

**List Flattening**
A final example is flattening lists. This is another common problem, and demonstrates just how powerful pure python is here.

```
# Nested list flattening.
pd.DataFrame(ser.tolist()).stack().reset_index(drop=True)  # stack
pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(ser.tolist())))         # itertools.chain
pd.Series([y for x in ser for y in x])                     # nested list comp
```

[image]

Both [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and the nested list comprehension are pure python constructs, and scale much better than the `stack` solution.

These timings are a strong indication of the fact that pandas is not equipped to work with mixed dtypes, and that you should probably refrain from using it to do so. Wherever possible, data should be present as scalar values (ints/floats/strings) in separate columns.

Lastly, the applicability of these solutions depend widely on your data. So, the best thing to do would be to test these operations on your data before deciding what to go with. Notice how I have not timed [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) on these solutions, because it would skew the graph (yes, it's that slow).

---

#### Regex Operations, and `.str` Accessor Methods

Pandas can apply regex operations such as [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), and [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall), as well as other "vectorized" string operations (such as `str.split`, `str.find`, `str.translate`, and so on) on string columns. These functions are slower than list comprehensions, and are meant to be more convenience functions than anything else.

It is usually much faster to pre-compile a regex pattern and iterate over your data with [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) (also see [Is it worth using Python's re.compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile)). The list comp equivalent to `str.contains` looks something like this:

```
p = re.compile(...)
ser2 = pd.Series([x for x in ser if p.search(x)])
```

Or,

```
ser2 = ser[[bool(p.search(x)) for x in ser]]
```

If you need to handle NaNs, you can do something like

```
ser[[bool(p.search(x)) if pd.notnull(x) else False for x in ser]]
```

The list comp equivalent to `str.extract` (without groups) will look something like:

```
df['col2'] = [p.search(x).group(0) for x in df['col']]
```

If you need to handle no-matches and NaNs, you can use a custom function (still faster!):

```
def matcher(x):
    m = p.search(str(x))
    if m:
        return m.group(0)
    return np.nan

df['col2'] = [matcher(x) for x in df['col']]
```

The `matcher` function is very extensible. It can be fitted to return a list for each capture group, as needed. Just extract query the `group` or `groups` attribute of the matcher object.

For `str.extractall`, change `p.search` to `p.findall`.

**String Extraction**
Consider a simple filtering operation. The idea is to extract 4 digits if it is preceded by an upper case letter.

```
# Extracting strings.
p = re.compile(r'(?<=[A-Z])(\d{4})')
def matcher(x):
    m = p.search(x)
    if m:
        return m.group(0)
    return np.nan

ser.str.extract(r'(?<=[A-Z])(\d{4})', expand=False)   #  str.extract
pd.Series([matcher(x) for x in ser])                  #  list comprehension
```

[image]

**More Examples**
Full disclosure - I am the author (in part or whole) of these posts listed below.

- [Fast punctuation removal with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444346/fast-punctuation-removal-with-pandas)
- [String concatenation of two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns/54298586#54298586)
- [Remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column/54302517#54302517)
- [Replace all but the last occurrence of a character in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47813144/4909087)

---

#### Conclusion

As shown from the examples above, iteration shines when working with small rows of DataFrames, mixed datatypes, and regular expressions.

The speedup you get depends on your data and your problem, so your mileage may vary. The best thing to do is to carefully run tests and see if the payout is worth the effort.

The "vectorized" functions shine in their simplicity and readability, so if performance is not critical, you should definitely prefer those.

Another side note, certain string operations deal with constraints that favour the use of NumPy. Here are two examples where careful NumPy vectorization outperforms python:

- [Create new column with incremental values in a faster and efficient way - Answer by Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471005/4909087)
- [Fast punctuation removal with pandas - Answer by Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50518852/4909087)

Additionally, sometimes just operating on the underlying arrays via `.values` as opposed to on the Series or DataFrames can offer a healthy enough speedup for most usual scenarios (see the **Note** in the **Numeric Comparison** section above). So, for example `df[df.A.values != df.B.values]` would show instant performance boosts over `df[df.A != df.B]`. Using `.values` may not be appropriate in every situation, but it is a useful hack to know.

As mentioned above, it's up to you to decide whether these solutions are worth the trouble of implementing.

---

#### Appendix: Code Snippets

```
import perfplot  
import operator 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
```

```
# Boolean indexing with Numeric value comparison.
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(1000, (n, 2)), columns=['A','B']),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: df[df.A != df.B],
        lambda df: df.query('A != B'),
        lambda df: df[[x != y for x, y in zip(df.A, df.B)]],
        lambda df: df[get_mask(df.A.values, df.B.values)]
    ],
    labels=['vectorized !=', 'query (numexpr)', 'list comp', 'numba'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N'
)
```

```
# Value Counts comparison.
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.Series(np.random.choice(1000, n)),
    kernels=[
        lambda ser: ser.value_counts(sort=False).to_dict(),
        lambda ser: dict(zip(*np.unique(ser, return_counts=True))),
        lambda ser: Counter(ser),
    ],
    labels=['value_counts', 'np.unique', 'Counter'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=lambda x, y: dict(x) == dict(y)
)
```

```
# Boolean indexing with string value comparison.
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(1000, (n, 2)), columns=['A','B'], dtype=str),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: df[df.A != df.B],
        lambda df: df.query('A != B'),
        lambda df: df[[x != y for x, y in zip(df.A, df.B)]],
    ],
    labels=['vectorized !=', 'query (numexpr)', 'list comp'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=None
)
```

```
# Dictionary value extraction.
ser1 = pd.Series([{'key': 'abc', 'value': 123}, {'key': 'xyz', 'value': 456}])
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([ser1] * n, ignore_index=True),
    kernels=[
        lambda ser: ser.map(operator.itemgetter('value')),
        lambda ser: pd.Series([x.get('value') for x in ser]),
    ],
    labels=['map', 'list comprehension'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=None
)
```

```
# List positional indexing. 
ser2 = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2], []])        
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([ser2] * n, ignore_index=True),
    kernels=[
        lambda ser: ser.map(get_0th),
        lambda ser: ser.str[0],
        lambda ser: pd.Series([x[0] if len(x) > 0 else np.nan for x in ser]),
        lambda ser: pd.Series([get_0th(x) for x in ser]),
    ],
    labels=['map', 'str accessor', 'list comprehension', 'list comp safe'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=None
)
```

```
# Nested list flattening.
ser3 = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g']])
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([ser2] * n, ignore_index=True),
    kernels=[
        lambda ser: pd.DataFrame(ser.tolist()).stack().reset_index(drop=True),
        lambda ser: pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(ser.tolist()))),
        lambda ser: pd.Series([y for x in ser for y in x]),
    ],
    labels=['stack', 'itertools.chain', 'nested list comp'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N',    
    equality_check=None
    
)
```

```
# Extracting strings.
ser4 = pd.Series(['foo xyz', 'test A1234', 'D3345 xtz'])
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([ser4] * n, ignore_index=True),
    kernels=[
        lambda ser: ser.str.extract(r'(?<=[A-Z])(\d{4})', expand=False),
        lambda ser: pd.Series([matcher(x) for x in ser])
    ],
    labels=['str.extract', 'list comprehension'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 15)],
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=None
)
```

Comment: `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` now support construction from iterables. That means one can simply pass a Python generator to the constructor functions rather than needing to construct a list first (using list comprehensions), which could be slower in many cases. However, the size of the generator output cannot be determined beforehand. I'm not sure how much time / memory overhead that would cause.

Comment: @GZ0 IIRC, accepting iterators is a more recent addition to the API. As for "that means one can simply pass a Python generator to the constructor functions rather than needing to construct a list first", I disagree. Memory maybe, performance no. In my experience it usually almost always faster to generate the list and pass it on. List comps FTW.

Comment: @cs95 Why don't you think generators can lead to performance gain? Or had you done any tests on that?

Comment: @GZ0 I didn't say generators do not lead to a performance gain, I'm saying you don't gain as much as you would using list comprehensions. There are overheads associated with initialising genexps, maintaining state, etc, which list comps don't have. There are a lot of examples here with list comprehensions that you can time against generator comprehensions to compare. Here's an example you can run right now: `ser = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g']] * 10000)` ;  `%timeit pd.Series(y for x in ser for y in x)` ;  `%timeit pd.Series([y for x in ser for y in x])`

Comment: @cs95 You are probably right. I just had a quick look into the constructor code of `pd.Series` and it turns out that if the size of the iterable output cannot be determined a list would be constructed from the iterable anyway. So in most cases there would be no gains to use generators. However when I ran the examples you gave the generator version is actually slower. I'm not sure where the difference comes from.

Comment: @cs95 After some investigation I think the difference is primarily attributed to `list()` calls being slower than list comprehensions.

Comment: @GZ0 That, plus the overhead of bookkeeping, maintaining state, etc. There is no gain whatsoever for any function that has to construct the list before using its values, as Series and DataFrame will do. [`str.join` is a case in point.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4909087)

Comment: @cs95 `str.join` is similar to `pd.Series` in that it also needs to know the total size of input before constructing the output. So if `pandas` and `numpy` use primarily fixed-sized arrays for the underlying implementation, which I assume is the case, then they have to know the total size beforehand.

Comment: @cs95 Note that for known-size iterables, it would be faster to construct `pd.Series` from them directly rather than converting them to lists, e.g. `pd.Series(range(10000))`, `pd.Series("a" * 10000)`, and `pd.Series(pd.Index(range(10000)))` would be much faster than their list counterparts (the last one was even slightly faster than `pd.Index.to_series`.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth analysis. Good examples of why never to make performance-oriented decisions without actually profiling.

Answer (score 6):

In short

- for loop + `iterrows` is extremely slow. Overhead isn't significant on ~1k rows, but noticeable on 10k+ rows.
- for loop + `itertuples` is much faster than `iterrows` or `apply`.
- vectorization is usually much faster than `itertuples`

Benchmark
[image]

Comment: Shocked this answer doesn't have more upvotes, with conciseness, data, and no mention of itertuples in the other answer.  People not seeing it?  Or is there reasons it's not as useful/valid as it looks to novices like me who aren't wise enough to know something?  Because it looks like itertuples (and list comprehension) are basically equivalent to vectorization in string parsing+decoding??

Comment: @JeopardyTempest, I think it's because it shows no code nor links to obtain the benchmarks. I trust most that which I can run, test, and duplicate. I want to see and run the code to produce those plots myself.

Comment: @artoby, can you please post the benchmark code which produced these plots, or a link to where you got these plots? I'd like to see and run the code myself to learn from it.

Comment: @GabrielStaples sure, here it is https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IhkGAkRYBjhY9-94ef9ydxQ78IJTpybJ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

> ##### Are for-loops in pandas really bad?

Yes, yes they are (for big calculations over lots of rows, at least). Check this out:

[image]

The slowest *4* of those 13 techniques which I tested all use `for` loops. They range from **300x~1400x** slower than the vectorized approaches!

That's pretty crazy. See my full answer here: [How to iterate over Pandas `DataFrame`s without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887).

> ##### When should I care?

1. If you're iterating over a lot of rows.
2. If you're tired of waiting for your calculations to finish.
3. If you want Python to use less electricity.

Again, look at the extreme difference in the plot above when computing over 2 million rows.

> ##### So, how come I sometimes see users suggesting loop-based solutions?

I suspect it's probably that they just don't know. Producing the plot above took me hundreds of hours of learning. If you see `for` loops, direct people to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887) and they can refer to the alternative techniques I present. Some of them are rather complicated, such as the pure vectorization approach with boolean indexing. And, even list comprehension isn't naturally intuitive. They just need someone to show them:

1. How slow the bad techniques are.
2. How to do the good techniques, with real code and real examples.

##### Should I care that `for` loops are bad?

Maybe not. Remember: *functional*, existing code is always better than *perfect*, non-existent code. And for small datasets, the run-time savings may not matter much (ex: 0.01 sec vs 0.2 sec).

I find if I wait longer than 1 second for my code to run, however, I want to know why.

And for 2 million rows, 30~135+ seconds is absolutely unbearable, especially considering the easy **list comprehension** solution is ~1 second, and the pure vectorization approach is 0.1 seconds.

### See also

1. My full answer: [How to iterate over Pandas `DataFrame`s without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270285/4561887)