# Replace string with corresponding string from another column with pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame called *df* that looks something like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'column1' : ['client#1 is #name#', 'client#2 is #name#'], 
    'column2': ['josh', 'max']}
)

              column1 column2
0  client#1 is #name#    josh
1  client#2 is #name#     max
```

I am trying to replace the phrase "*#name*" in column1 with the value of column2. I want the end result to look like this:

[image]

I have tried a few approaches like the following:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].replace(["#name#"], df['column2'])
```

But I am not sure of how to grab the specific phrase '*#name#*' in column1 and replace it with the value of column2. Any suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's strings, and if there are no NaNs, I would recommend calling `str.replace` inside a list comprehension for speed:

```
df['column1'] = [
    x.replace('#name#', y) for x, y in zip(df.column1, df.column2)]

df
            column1 column2
0  client#1 is josh    josh
1   client#2 is max     max
```

Why are list comprehensions worth it for string operations? You can read more at [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care).

---

Another interesting option you can consider is `str.replace` with `iter`:

```
it = iter(df.column2)
df['column1'] = df.column1.str.replace('#name#', lambda x: next(it))

df
            column1 column2
0  client#1 is josh    josh
1   client#2 is max     max
```

Should handle NaNs and mixed dtypes just fine (but will be slower).

---

A simpler `replace` option by @Vaishali, which will work if the "#name#" substring is always at the end of the string.

```
df['column1'] = df.column1.add(df.column2).str.replace('#name#', '')
df
            column1 column2
0  client#1 is josh    josh
1   client#2 is max     max
```

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed this really helps and clarifies what I am trying to do!

Comment: @user3116949 Word of advice, try to make sure your questions conform to the site guidelines. This means all data should be present as runnable code in your question.

Comment: Or simply df.column1.add(df.column2).str.replace('#name#', '') :)

Comment: @Vaishali Ah that is a nice one and will work, assuming "#name#" is always at the end of the string.