# Getting the first element from each list in a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns consisting of lists of numbers:

```
idx codes       new_column
0   [12,18,5]
1   [22,15]
2   [4]
3   [15,1]
```

How can I add a new column to the dataframe consisting of the first list entry of the codes column:

```
idx codes     new_column
0   [12,18,5]  12
1   [22,15]    22
2   [4]         4
3   [15,1]     15

I tried:
    df['new_column']=df['codes'][0]

However, that didn't work.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is using `str.get`

```
# df['new_column'] = df['codes'].str.get(0)
df['new_column'] = df['codes'].str[0]
```

However, I would suggest a list comprehension for speed, if there are no NaNs:

```
df['new_column'] = [l[0] for l in df['codes']]
```

If lists can be empty, you can do something like:

```
df['new_column'] = [l[0] if len(l) > 0 else np.nan for l in df['codes']]
```

---

To handle NaNs with the list comprehension, you can use `loc` to subset and assign back.

```
m = df['codes'].notna()
df.loc[m, 'new_column'] = [
    l[0] if len(l) > 0 else np.nan for l in df.loc[m, 'codes']]
```

Obligatory why-is-list-comp-worth-it link: [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

Comment: I tried df['codes'].str[0] and on 285,000 records it was very fast, about 2 sec.  would list comprehension be even faster?

Comment: @afshin Yes! Try it.

Comment: It is interesting that `pd.Series.str` is really useful regardless of what the value of the content is... even a list of Dict objects works well with this method, if you want to access a key like the first author in a list of dictionaries in a complex column and count the unique authors: `node_df["authors"].str[0].str["#text"].unique().count()`