# Select rows in pandas dataframe if all the columns contain certain pattern

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe

```
id  pattern1    pattern2    pattern3
 1  a-b-c       a-b--       a-b-c
 2  a-a--       a-b--       a-c--
 3  a-v--       a-m--       a-k--
 4  a-b--       a-n--       a-n-c
```

I want to filter rows that contains the pattern -- at the end in all the columns.
In this case the output would be

```
 2  a-a--       a-b--       a-c--
 3  a-v--       a-m--       a-k--
```

So far I can only think of doing something like the following

```
df[(len(df['pattern1'].str.split('--')[1])==0) & \
   (len(df['pattern2'].str.split('--')[1])==0) & \
   (len(df['pattern3'].str.split('--')[1])==0)]
```

This doesn't work.Also,I can't write the names of all the columns as tehre are 20 columns.
How can I filter rows where all the columns in that row match certain pattern/condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with setting "id" as the index, if not yet done.

```
df = df.set_index('id')
```

One option to check each string is using `applymap` calling `str.endswith`:

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: x.endswith('--')).all(1)]

   pattern1 pattern2 pattern3
id                           
2     a-a--    a-b--    a-c--
3     a-v--    a-m--    a-k--
```

---

Another option is `apply` calling `pd.Series.str.endswith` for each column:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.endswith('--')).all(1)]

   pattern1 pattern2 pattern3
id                           
2     a-a--    a-b--    a-c--
3     a-v--    a-m--    a-k--
```

---

Lastly, for performance, you can AND masks inside a list comprehension using `logical_and.reduce`:

```
# m = np.logical_and.reduce([df[c].str.endswith('--') for c in df.columns])
m = np.logical_and.reduce([
    [x.endswith('--') for x in df[c]] for c in df.columns])
m
# array([False,  True,  True, False])

df[m]
   pattern1 pattern2 pattern3
id                           
2     a-a--    a-b--    a-c--
3     a-v--    a-m--    a-k--
```

---

If there are other columns, but you only want to consider those named "pattern*", you can use `filter` on the DataFrame:

```
u = df.filter(like='pattern')
```

Now repeat the options above using `u`, for example, the first option will be

```
df[u.applymap(lambda x: x.endswith('--')).all(1)]
```

...and so on.

Comment: Why would I suggest loops here? If you're interested, read my writeup at [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)