# Delete Pandas DataFrame row if contains character

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to remove any row that contains a "?" in a particular column.

I have this line:

```
df[~df.C.str.contains("?")]
```

which doesn't work. I get the following error:

> error: nothing to repeat at position 0

However the following does work

```
df[~df.C.str.contains("abc")]
```

Does anyone know what it is about ? that stops it running?

Comment: `df[~df.C.str.contains("?",regex=False)]` ?

Comment: @BradSolomon - looking for better dupe

Comment: @BradSolomon check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219706/pandas-not-counting-rows-properly

Comment: Yep - thats a better match, no pun intended @jezrael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.str.contains()` expects a regular expression by default; [`?` is treated as a metacharacter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), and using it alone will raise `re.error`.*  Pass `regex=False` to search for a literal "?" character:

```
df[~df.C.str.contains("?", regex=False)]
```

---

<sub>* See `re.compile("?")`</sub>

Comment: Thanks that works. Couldn't find an answer anywhere. I'll accept once timer expires