# How to split this data in Python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The is my pandas data frame, In the index column i want to keep only the values after double underscore(__) and remove the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with parameter `n=1` for split by first splitter (if possible multiple `__`) and select second lists:

```
df['index'].str.split('__', n=1).str[1]
```

Or use list comprehension if no missing values and performance is important:

```
df['last'] = [x.split('__', 1)[1] for x in df['index']]
```

Comment: Why is a list comprehension a good alternative for string operations? For more information, see my writeup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care).

Comment: It works fine. Along with the index field, i just want to get all the columns? Any way?

Comment: @ShankarPanda - So need `df1 = df.join(df['index'].str.split('__', expand=True))` ?

Comment: perfect !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`df['index'].apply(lambda x: x.split('__')[-1])` will do the trick