# Frequency counts for a pandas column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame and a column contained a string that was separated by a pipe.  These were from movie genres.  They looked like this:

```
Genre
Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
Comedy|Romance
...
```

I used str.split to get them back into the cell as a List.  Like this:

```
Genre 
[Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fantasy]
[Adventure, Children, Fantasy]
[Comedy, Romance]
[Comedy, Drama, Romance]
[Comedy]
```

I want to get a sum of all the genres.  For example how many times did Comedy appear? How many times did Adventure and so on?  I can't seem to figure this out.

This would look like

```
Comedy    4
Adventure 2
Animation 1
(...and so on...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As somebody from the for-loop club, I recommend using python's C-accelerated routines—`itertools.chain`, and `collections.Counter`—for performance.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

pd.Series(
    Counter(chain.from_iterable(x.split('|') for x in df.Genre)))

Adventure    1
Animation    1
Children     1
Comedy       2
Fantasy      1
Romance      1
dtype: int64
```

Why do I think CPython functions are better than pandas "vectorised" string functions? They are inherently hard to vectorise. You can read more at [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care).

---

If you have to deal with NaNs, you can call a function that handles exceptions gracefully:

```
def try_split(x):
    try:
        return x.split('|')
    except AttributeError:
        return []

pd.Series(
    Counter(chain.from_iterable(try_split(x) for x in df.Genre)))
```

---

pandaically, you would do this with `split`, `stack`, and `value_counts`.

```
df['Genre'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().value_counts()

Comedy       2
Romance      1
Children     1
Animation    1
Fantasy      1
Adventure    1
dtype: int64
```

---

The timing difference is obvious even for tiny DataFrames.

```
%timeit df['Genre'].str.get_dummies(sep='|').sum()
%timeit df['Genre'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
%%timeit
pd.Series(
    Counter(chain.from_iterable(try_split(x) for x in df.Genre)))

2.8 ms ± 68.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.4 ms ± 210 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
320 µs ± 9.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for all the examples! I learned a ton with that! I ended up trying a few ways and you're very correct to point out the timing.  I have only 27,000 records and it's noticeable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm also in favor of using `chain`+`for`.

Just to document this, one more possible way is to use `get_dummies`

```
df['Genre'].str.get_dummies(sep='|').sum()
```