# Count frequencies (unique rows) from a pandas list type column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`df`) like this:

```
id  col
1  [A, B, C, C]
2  [B, C, D]
3  [C, D, E]
```

And, I have list like this:

```
l = ["A", "C", "F"]
```

For each element in `l`, I want to count the **unique rows** they appear in `df`.

```
'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'F': 0
```

But I'm not getting the part where I can check if the value exists in the `list-column` of the dataframe.

```py
d = {}
for i in l:
    df_tmp = df[i.isin(df['col'])]['id'] ## wrong, showing error, isin is not a string attribute
    d[i] = len(df_tmp)
```

Anyway I can fix this? Or is there a more cleaner/efficient way?

N.B. There is a similar question [Frequency counts for a pandas column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281070/frequency-counts-for-a-pandas-column-of-lists), but it is different as I have an external list to check the frequency.

Comment: The 'isin' function needs to be called on the dataframe itself-- not the string you are using. it would be more like df.isin(i). Here is the link to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: @Mitchnoff yes, `isin()` can be used to check if dataframe values is in a list. But, here I've to do the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method that applies given function to each element of the column (in our case it is the function that tests whether an element belongs to the list or not), then we sum `True` values, i.e. rows in which we found requested values and eventually save it to the dictionary. And we do it for all requested letters. I have not tested performance of this solution.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'id': 1, 'col': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']},
        {'id': 2, 'col': ['B', 'C', 'D']},
        {'id': 3, 'col': ['C', 'D', 'E']}])
    
    letters = ["A", "C", "D", "F"]
    res = {v: df['col'].apply(lambda x: v in x).sum()
           for v in letters}

    # output
    # {'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'D': 2, 'F': 0}
```

Comment: This doesn't match OPs desired output, where C is 4.

Comment: Desired output is C=3, as it is written in the question. OP needs number of unique rows that contain the letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the membership in the list for each value in ['A', 'C',  'F'] and compute `sum()` like:

```
vals = ['A', 'C', 'F']
{val: df['col'].apply(lambda x: val in x).sum() for val in vals}
```

output:

```
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'F': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` `col` column and keep rows where value in `l` list then use `value_counts()` to count value in Series.

```py
l = ["A", "C", "D", "F"]

col = df['col'].apply(set).explode(ignore_index=True)
out = col[col.isin(l)].value_counts().reindex(l, fill_value=0).to_dict()

# or without define `col`

out = (df['col'].apply(set).explode(ignore_index=True)
       [lambda d: d.isin(l)]
       .value_counts().reindex(l, fill_value=0).to_dict())
```

```
print(out)

{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'D': 2, 'F': 0}
```

Comment: There are two issues: (1) its not showing the values that are not in the dataframe (`F`) and (2) if one row has duplicate values, it will show in the count.

Comment: @user3503711 See the update