# Change Column Data Type in More Pythonic Way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, label

Please help me be more pythonic:

I am label encoding all categorical features with Pandas. I know this can also be done with Sklearn but I'd like to do it with Pandas or Python alone.

I did this by first selecting all columns of type 'obj' which happened to be cat (I am dealing with a small dataframe so I know this for sure). Then, I used a for loop to convert each column.

I know I can definitely do this by avoiding the for loop. The more pythonic the better:

```
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

for col in cat_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care) for loop is not always 'bad', if you do need get ride of it , you can using `apply`

```
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
df[cat_cols ] = df[cat_cols ].apply(lambda x : x.astype('category').cat.codes,axis=1)
```

Comment: Well but based on the above, the second line of code only gets applied to one column. How would I get it to apply to all columns in the cat_cols list?

Comment: @Odisseo sorry change col to cat_cols

Comment: Just for record, the solution above actually takes longer than the original with the for loop