# Replace pandas Dataframe column values with the list if it matches a word

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of colors like this:

```
color = ['green', 'blue', 'red']
```

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
df:
col1        col2
 A        dark green
 B        sea blue
 C          blue
 D       exclusive red
 E          green
 F       pale red
```

I want to match `col2` with the `color` list. If any word of `col2` matches the element of the `color` list, replace it with the lists value.

The result data frame will be

```
 col1          col2
  A            green
  B            blue
  C            blue
  D            red
  E            green
  F            red
```

What is the most efficient way to do it using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with joined values by `|` for regex `OR`, last add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace non matched values (`NaN`s) by original column:

```
print (df)
  col1           col2
0    A     dark green
1    B       sea blue
2    C           blue
3    D  exclusive red
4    E          green
5    F           pale <- not matched value

color=['green','blue','red']

pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(color))
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).fillna(df['col2'])

print (df)
  col1   col2
0    A  green
1    B   blue
2    C   blue
3    D    red
4    E  green
5    F   pale
```

Comment: if the color doesnt't match how to keep keep the original color ? I don't want nan values there.

Comment: @KallolSamanta You can check the other answer as well, it answers the question. I suggest timing all the solution and ticking the best one for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract`:

```
df['col2'] = df.col2.str.extract(f"({'|'.join(color)})", expand=False)
df

  col1   col2
0    A  green
1    B   blue
2    C   blue
3    D    red
4    E  green
5    F    red
```

---

For better performance, you can use a list comprehension that uses a precompiled regex pattern to perform `re.search`:

```
import re

p = re.compile(rf"({'|'.join(color)})")
def try_extract(s):
    try:
        return p.search(s).group(1)
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        return s
```

```
df['col2'] = [try_extract(s) for s in df['col2']
df

  col1   col2
0    A  green
1    B   blue
2    C   blue
3    D    red
4    E  green
5    F    red
```

---

> If the color doesn't match how to keep keep the original color? I
>   don't want nan values there.

This is automatically handled by `try_except`:

```
df2 = df.append(pd.Series(
    {'col1': 'G', 'col2': 'something else'}), ignore_index=True)
df2['col2'] = [try_extract(s) for s in df2['col2']]
df2

  col1            col2
0    A           green
1    B            blue
2    C            blue
3    D             red
4    E           green
5    F             red
6    G  something else   # other values are preserved.
```

For more information on why list comprehensions should be considered a competitive alternative, you can check [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care).