# Convert column values to NaN using np.where

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I cannot figure out how to use the index results from np.where in a for loop. I want to use this for loop to ONLY change the values of a column given the np.where index results.

This is a hypothetical example for a situation where I want to find the indexed location of certain problems or anomalies in my dataset, grab their locations with np.where, and then run a loop on the dataframe to recode them as NaN, while leaving every other index untouched.

Here is my simple code attempt so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# import iris
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocketfish88/democ/master/iris.csv')

# conditional np.where -- hypothetical problem data
find_error = np.where((df['petal_length'] == 1.6) & 
                  (df['petal_width'] == 0.2))

# loop over column to change error into NA
for i in enumerate(find_error):
    df = df['species'].replace({'setosa': np.nan})

# df[i] is a problem but I cannot figure out how to get around this or an alternative
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly assign to the column:

```
m = (df['petal_length'] == 1.6) & (df['petal_width'] == 0.2)
df.loc[m, 'species'] = np.nan
```

Or, fixing your code.

```
df['species'] = np.where(m, np.nan, df['species'])
```

Or, using `Series.mask`:

```
df['species'] = df['species'].mask(m)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really great! Any stabs on a loop (I am trying to get better at them but I am really bad at loops).

Comment: @JohnStud There are cases when loops are useful, but generally do not recommend their use on numeric data (especially when vectorised methods exist). Loops are good for string/regex operations. I have a detailed writeup on that here: [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

Comment: Thanks again! Much appreciated help!

Comment: Actually.. I am getting errors on every single one of these suggestions!

Comment: @JohnStud Okay, that's not particularly... helpful. What does the error say? Please provide the error message as well.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what the issue was. I just re-ran everything and got it to work. The first issue was; AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: @JohnStud You must've mistakenly reassigned `df` to something else (not a DataFrame, at least).