# Concatenate 2 Pandas list-filled columns into 1 big list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     NAME      total           total_temp
ID                                      
1     CVS     [abc1]       [cba, xyzzy01]
2  Costco     [bcd2, 22]   [dcb, xyzzy02]
3   Apple     [cde3]       [edc, xyzzy03]
```

I want to add create a new column total_temp_2 so that the data looks like this:

```
     NAME      total       total_temp                   total_temp_2
ID                                                  
1     CVS     [abc1]       [cba, xyzzy01]       [abc1, cba, xyzzy01]
2  Costco     [bcd2, 22]   [dcb, xyzzy02]   [bcd2, 22, dcb, xyzzy02]
3   Apple     [cde3]       [edc, xyzzy03]       [cde3, edc, xyzzy03]
```

I feel like I could guess my way through really inefficient ways to concatenate the lists, but I suspect I'm missing something I don't know about Pandas.

How can i achieve this operation using pandas?

Comment: I can't see why your solution `df['total'] + df['total_temp']` isn't working. If those are lists it should combine them together

Comment: Should not have issue . even it is str , it should not have errors

Comment: All right ... I'm an idiot ... I forgot that for some testing reason or another, I had putzed around with my data, and that I was actually dealing with the string `'[dcb, xyzzy02]'`, not the list `[dcb, xyzzy02]`.  Simple answer works now that both columns are full of proper lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with mixed types, [I usually recommend using something like a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care) which has minimal memory and performance overhead.

```
df['total_temp_2'] = [x + y for x, y in zip(df['total'], df['total_temp'])]
df

      NAME       total      total_temp              total_temp_2
ID                                                              
1      CVS      [abc1]  [cba, xyzzy01]      [abc1, cba, xyzzy01]
2   Costco  [bcd2, 22]  [dcb, xyzzy02]  [bcd2, 22, dcb, xyzzy02]
3    Apple      [cde3]  [edc, xyzzy03]      [cde3, edc, xyzzy03]
```

If these are columns of strings, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse them:

```
import ast

c = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns
df[c] = df[c].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

If the solution above throws `ValueError: malformed node or string:`, try using the [`yaml`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) package instead.

```
import yaml
df = df.applymap(yaml.load)
```

---

Funnily enough, simple addition works for me on 0.24.

```
df['total'] + df['total_temp']

ID
1        [abc1, cba, xyzzy01]
2    [bcd2, 22, dcb, xyzzy02]
3        [cde3, edc, xyzzy03]
dtype: object
```

These also work,

```
df['total'].add(df['total_temp'])

ID
1        [abc1, cba, xyzzy01]
2    [bcd2, 22, dcb, xyzzy02]
3        [cde3, edc, xyzzy03]
dtype: object
```

```
df['total_temp'].radd(df['total'])

ID
1        [abc1, cba, xyzzy01]
2    [bcd2, 22, dcb, xyzzy02]
3        [cde3, edc, xyzzy03]
dtype: object
```

These are great in terms of simplicity, but inherently loopy since mixed type operations are harder to vectorize.

Comment: All right ... I'm an idiot ... I forgot that for some testing reason or another, I had putzed around with my data, and that I was actually dealing with the string `'[dcb, xyzzy02]'`, not the list `[dcb, xyzzy02]`.  Simple answer works now that both columns are full of proper lists.  Thanks for the alternatives in case I ever get into a pinch, though!

Comment: @k.. I've edited your question so your mistake is less obvious now :-)

Comment: @anky_91 Amended!

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like this (wanting to apply a function to a dataframe I usually go to `.apply()`. So I would run this:

```py
df['total_temp_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['total'] + x['total_temp'], axis=1)
```

Using the built-in pandas functionality is optimal for this type of transformation.