# check element-wise for existence of string

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm looking for a way to check whether one string can be found in another string. `str.contains` only takes a fixed string pattern as argument, I'd rather like to have an element-wise comparison between two string columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'long': ['sometext', 'someothertext', 'evenmoretext'],
               'short': ['some', 'other', 'stuff']})


# This fails:
df['short_in_long'] = df['long'].str.contains(df['short'])
```

Expected Output:

```
[True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `zip`:

```
df['short_in_long'] = [b in a for a, b in zip(df['long'], df['short'])]

print (df)
            long  short  short_in_long
0       sometext   some           True
1  someothertext  other           True
2   evenmoretext  stuff          False
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a prime use case for a list comprehension:

```
# df['short_in_long'] = [y in x for x, y in df[['long', 'short']].values.tolist()]
df['short_in_long'] = [y in x for x, y in df[['long', 'short']].values]
df

            long  short  short_in_long
0       sometext   some           True
1  someothertext  other           True
2   evenmoretext  stuff          False
```

List comprehensions are usually faster than string methods because of lesser overhead. See [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care).

---

If your data contains NaNs, you can call a function with error handling:

```
def try_check(haystack, needle):
    try:
        return needle in haystack
    except TypeError:
        return False

df['short_in_long'] = [try_check(x, y) for x, y in df[['long', 'short']].values]
```

Answer (score 3):

Check with `numpy`, it is row-wise :-) .

```
np.core.char.find(df.long.values.astype(str),df.short.values.astype(str))!=-1
Out[302]: array([ True,  True, False])
```

Comment: I used `numpy` a well. I was trying `df['short_in_long'] = np.where(df['short'].str.contains(df['long']), True, False)`. Why does this not work row-wise?

Comment: @Erfan isin will not check the partial match :-)

Comment: Sorry, that was my second try. I edited my comment.

Comment: @Erfan two part , `str.contain` do not accept `Series`, second , if you using join string with `sep = '|'` when the 3rd row have any partial string like `some` and `other`, the 3rd row will return as True under  `str.contain`

Comment: Thank you, so when using `sep = '|'` It would check each row over the whole column.

Comment: @Erfan yes that is why when do rowwise check like 1-1 , we can not using str.contains

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
df['short_in_long'] = df['long'].str.contains('|'.join(df['short'].values))
```

**Update :**
I misinterpreted the problem. Here is the corrected version:

```
df['short_in_long'] = df['long'].apply(lambda x: True if x[1] in x[0] else False, axis =1)
```

Comment: It was my first wrong answer. OP need check values per rows.

Comment: As @jezrael mentioned , op want a row-wise check (1-1 check ), not (1-n) check

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected my code for one-to-one row-wise checking.