# Pandas - slicing column values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I slice column values based on first & last character location indicators from two other columns?

**Here is the code for a sample df:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'W': ['abcde','abcde','abcde','abcde']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['First']=[0,0,0,0]
df['Last']=[1,2,3,5]
df['Slice']=['a','ab','abc','abcde']

print(df.head())
```

**Code output:**

### [image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it with for loop , you may worry about the speed , please check [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

```
df['Slice']=[x[y:z]for x,y,z in zip(df.W,df.First,df.Last)]
df
Out[918]: 
       W  First  Last  Slice
0  abcde      0     1      a
1  abcde      0     2     ab
2  abcde      0     3    abc
3  abcde      0     5  abcde
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this will be faster, but a similar approach would be:

```
df['Slice'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0][x[1]:x[2]],axis=1)
```

Briefly, you go through each row (`axis=1`) and apply a custom function. The function takes the row (stored as `x`), and slices the first element using the second and third elements as indices for the slicing (that's the `lambda` part). I will be happy to elaborate more if this isn't clear.