# pandas - str (row) slicing based on int in another column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a df:

```
   colA    colB
0 'abcde'    4
1 'abcde'    2
2 'abcde'    1
3  np.nan   np.nan
4 'wxyz'     3
5 'wxyz'     2
```

What I would like is to be able to remove the first X characters from colA based on the value in colB and return the value to a new column C like below.

```
   colA    colB     colC
0 'abcde'    4      'e'
1 'abcde'    2      'cde'
2 'abcde'    1      'bcde'
3  np.nan   np.nan  np.nan
4 'wxyz'     3      'z'
5 'wxyz'     2      'yz'
```

I've tried some .apply lambda's here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250558/pandas-slicing-column-values-based-on-another-column) with .str[x:] but running into trouble saving it back due to null values in other rows.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: may nan rows be removed?

Comment: Those quotes in the data are there in actual data or you have included them? @swifty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom function for return missing values if indexing failed:

```
def f(a, b):
    try:
        return a[int(b):]
    except:
        return np.nan

df['colC'] = [f(a,b) for a, b in zip(df['colA'], df['colB'])]
```

Or:

```
df['colC'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x['colA'], x['colB']), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
    colA  colB  colC
0  abcde   4.0     e
1  abcde   2.0   cde
2  abcde   1.0  bcde
3    NaN   NaN   NaN
4   wxyz   3.0     z
5   wxyz   2.0    yz
```

Another idea with test non missing values:

```
df['colC'] = [a[int(b):] if pd.notna(a) and pd.notna(b) 
                         else np.nan 
                         for a, b in zip(df['colA'], df['colB'])]
print (df)
    colA  colB  colC
0  abcde   4.0     e
1  abcde   2.0   cde
2  abcde   1.0  bcde
3    NaN   NaN   NaN
4   wxyz   3.0     z
5   wxyz   2.0    yz
```

Answer (score 0):

[jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265773/5637137) is probably best and more readable, but if you want to do it in a oneliner you can use [`df.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). Despite the scary name, it won't alter your original DataFrame unless you call it with the parameter `inplace=True`.

```py
>>> df['colC'] = df.dropna().apply(lambda x: x[0][int(x[1]):], axis=1)

>>> print(df)
    colA    colB    colC
0   abcde   4.0     e
1   abcde   2.0     cde
2   abcde   1.0     bcde
3   NaN     NaN     NaN
4   wxyz    3.0     z
5   wxyz    2.0     yz
```