# Remove rows if it exists in the previous group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a GroupBy object. I want to to remove rows from current group if the same row exists in the previous group. Let's say this is (n-1)th group:

```
    A   B
0   foo 0
1   baz 1
2   foo 1
3   bar 1
```

And this n-th group

```
    A   B
0   foo 2
1   foo 1
2   baz 1
3   baz 3
```

After dropping all duplicates. Result of n-th group:

```
    A   B
0   foo 2
3   baz 3
```

**EDIT:**

I would like to achieve it without loop if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using `merge` with `indicator` here

```
yourdf=dfn.merge(df1,indicator=True,how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both']
yourdf
     A  B     _merge
0  foo  2  left_only
3  baz  3  left_only
#yourdf.drop('_merge',1,inplace=True)
```

Since it is `GrouBy Object` so you can do with for loop here , using above code for n times

Comment: Any way to achieve it without loop?

Comment: @DeveScie yes, it will need for loop , but for loop not always bad practice :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care