# How to combine non-null entries of columns of a DataFrame into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column that has a list of all entries of past columns that are non-null.

I would like to be able to be able to produce the desired column without having to iterate through each of the rows.

```
  col1   col2   col3   output       
  a      NaN    b      [a,b]        
  c      d      e      [c,d,e]      
  f      g      NaN    [f,g]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.agg` to call `dropna` and `tolist`:

```
df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)

0       [a, b]
1    [c, d, e]
2       [f, g]
dtype: object
```

If you need comma separated string instead, use `str.cat` or `str.join`:

```
df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)
# df.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)

0      a,b
1    c,d,e
2      f,g
dtype: object
```

---

If performance is important, I recommend the use of a list comprehension:

```
df['output'] = [x[pd.notna(x)].tolist() for x in df.values]
df

  col1 col2 col3     output
0    a  NaN    b     [a, b]
1    c    d    e  [c, d, e]
2    f    g  NaN     [f, g]
```

This works because your DataFrame consists of strings. For more information on when loops are appropriate to use with pandas, see this discussion: [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

Answer (score 2):

Using for loop

```
df['New']=[[y for y in x if y == y ] for x in df.values.tolist()]
df
Out[654]: 
  col1 col2 col3        New
0    a  NaN    b     [a, b]
1    c    d    e  [c, d, e]
2    f    g  NaN     [f, g]
```

Or using `stack` with `groupby`

```
df['New']=df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
df
Out[659]: 
  col1 col2 col3        New
0    a  NaN    b     [a, b]
1    c    d    e  [c, d, e]
2    f    g  NaN     [f, g]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_list(), axis=1)`