# Appending Pandas DataFrame column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
| Index | Value        |
|-------|--------------|
| 1     | [1, 12, 123] |
| 2     | [12, 123, 1] |
| 3     | [123, 12, 1] |
```

and **I want to append third column with list of array elements lengths**:

```
| Index | Value        | Expected_value |
|-------|--------------|----------------|
| 1     | [1, 12, 123] | [1, 2, 3]      |
| 2     | [12, 123, 1] | [2, 3, 1]      |
| 3     | [123, 12, 1] | [3, 2, 1]      |
```

I've tried to use python lambda function and mapping little bit like this:

```
dataframe["Expected_value"] = dataframe.value.map(lambda x: len(str(x)))
```

but instead of list **I got sum of those lengths**:

```
| Index | Value        | Expected_value |
|-------|--------------|----------------|
| 1     | [1, 12, 123] | 6              |
| 2     | [12, 123, 1] | 6              |
| 3     | [123, 12, 1] | 6              |
```

Comment: It's me or that `6` in `Expected value` is not correct? My mind is blowing

Comment: somehow I got integer - hadn't checked if this is sum of values of lengts or was it just lengths of lists from Value column

Comment: Ah you inserted values by hand, I thought It was the exact `map` output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` with `map`:

```
dataframe["Expected_value"] = dataframe.Value.map(lambda x: [len(str(y)) for y in x])
```

Or nested list comprehension:

```
dataframe["Expected_value"] = [[len(str(y)) for y in x] for x in dataframe.Value]
```

There is also possible use alternative for get lengths of integers:

```
import math
dataframe["Expected_value"] = [[int(math.log10(y))+1 for y in x] for x in dataframe.Value]
```

---

```
print (dataframe)
   Index         Value Expected_value
0      1  [1, 12, 123]      [1, 2, 3]
1      2  [12, 123, 1]      [2, 3, 1]
2      3  [123, 12, 1]      [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to read the clipboard like this? `sep='\|+'` not work.

Comment: @ResidentSleeper - Unfortunately I have to copy to text file and change formating, not very nice way...

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[[len(str(y)) for y in x] for x in df['Value'].tolist()]
# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1]]

df['Expected_value'] = [[len(str(y)) for y in x] for x in df['Value'].tolist()]
df

   Index         Value Expected_value
0      1  [1, 12, 123]      [1, 2, 3]
1      2  [12, 123, 1]      [2, 3, 1]
2      3  [123, 12, 1]      [3, 2, 1]
```

If you need to handle missing data,

```
def foo(x):
    try:
       return [len(str(y)) for y in x]
    except TypeError:
        return np.nan

df['Expected_value'] = [foo(x) for x in df['Value'].tolist()]
df

   Index         Value Expected_value
0      1  [1, 12, 123]      [1, 2, 3]
1      2  [12, 123, 1]      [2, 3, 1]
2      3  [123, 12, 1]      [3, 2, 1]
```

It is probably the best in terms of performance when dealing with object type data. More reading at [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care).

---

Another solution with `pd.DataFrame`, `applymap` and `agg`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Value'].tolist()).astype(str).applymap(len).agg(list, axis=1)

0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [2, 3, 1]
2    [3, 2, 1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Like the function to catch `NaN`!

Comment: Thanks @Erfan! I blame my mac for autocorrecting. "groupby" also used to be corrected to "groupie", it was quite irritating until I learned how to fix it.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I can imagine, had same problem