# How to slice date from a timestamp and convert to string?

Tags: python, pandas

My list of timestamps is given below:

```
time_list = 
[Timestamp('2019-01-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-01-27 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-01-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-02-08 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-02-09 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-02-10 00:00:00')]
```

I would like to take only the date part and convert it to a string. My code is

```
aux1 = []
for i in time_list:     
    aux1.append(str(i))
date_list = aux1
```

Present output is:

```
date_list = 
['2019-01-24 00:00:00',
 '2019-01-27 00:00:00',
 '2019-01-29 00:00:00',
 '2019-02-08 00:00:00',
 '2019-02-09 00:00:00',
 '2019-02-10 00:00:00']
```

However the output I want is:

`date_list = 
['2019-01-24',
 '2019-01-27',
 '2019-01-29',
 '2019-02-08',
 '2019-02-09',
 '2019-02-10']`

In my code I have used `for` loop approach but it is not producing the desired answer. Is there a better approach to get my desired `date_list`?

Comment: `aux1.append(i.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` ?

Comment: try `str(i)[:10]` apparently `'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable` but the string is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html) in list comprehension or loop:

```
date_list = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in time_list]
```

---

```
date_list = []
for i in time_list:     
    date_list.append(i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Or use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) with converting to `list`:

```
date_list = pd.DatetimeIndex(time_list).strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
print (date_list)
['2019-01-24', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-29', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-09', '2019-02-10']
```

Comment: I preferred your third approach because it does not have any `for` loop. This worked perfectly. Thanks a ton. Can you clarify my doubt, that is, using `for` loop is it a bad code?

Comment: @Msquare - It depends, but short answer is dont use loops, if exist vectorized alternative. More info about this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dt.strftime`

**Ex:**

```
aux1 = []
for i in time_list:     
    aux1.append(i.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
date_list = aux1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

```
import dateutil.parser


date_list = ['2019-01-24 00:00:00',
 '2019-01-27 00:00:00',
 '2019-01-29 00:00:00',
 '2019-02-08 00:00:00',
 '2019-02-09 00:00:00',
 '2019-02-10 00:00:00']

for data in date_list:

   dates = dateutil.parser.parse(data).date()
   print(dates)
```