# How to search for a word in a column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has reviews in it an I want to search for a specific word in all of the columns.

```
df["Summary"].str.lower().str.contains("great", na=False)
```

This gives the outcome as true or false, but I want to create a new column with 1 or 0 written in the corresponding rows.

For example if the review has 'great' in it it should give as 1, not 2.
I tried this:

```
if df["Summary"].str.lower().str.contains("great", na=False) == True:
    df["Great"] = '1'
else:
    df["Great"] = '0'
```

It gives this error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). How can I solve this?

Comment: Try [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).  `df["Great"] = np.where(df["Summary"].str.lower().contains("great", na=False), '1', '0')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since True/False corresponds to 1/0, all you need is an `astype` conversion from `bool` to `int`:

```
df['Great'] = df["Summary"].str.contains("great", case=False, na=False).astype(int)
```

Also note I've removed the `str.lower` call and added `case=False` as an argument to `str.contains` for a case insensitive comparison.

---

Another solution would be to lowercase and then disable the regex matching for better performance.

```
df['Great'] = (df["Summary"].str.lower()
                            .str.contains("great", regex=False, na=False)
                            .astype(int))
```

---

Finally, you can also use a list comprehension:

```
df['Great'] = [1 if 'great' in s.lower() else 0 for s in df['Summary']]
```

If you need to handle numeric data as well, use

```
df['Great'] = [
    1 if isinstance(s, str) and 'great' in s.lower() else 0 
    for s in df['Summary']
]
```

I've detailed the advantages of list comprehensions for object data ad nauseam in this post of mine: [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition
    df["Summary"].str.lower().str.contains("great", na=False)

Will return a series of True or False values. It won't be equal to "True" because a series is not a python boolean.
Instead you can do this to achieve what you want

```
df['Great'] = df['Summary'].apply(lambda x: 'great' in x.lower())
```

Comment: `apply` has limited use cases and should be avoided when there are better (read: vectorized/inbuilt) alternatives. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code).

Comment: thanks for this, I'm going to start using .str accessor over apply now

Comment: Happy coding :))

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
df["Great"] = np.where(df["Summary"].str.lower().contains("great", na=False), '1', '0')
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).