# Filter Dataframe if column is in any part of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter a dataframe to rows with column values that are in a list. However, the value in the column will not be an exact match to the list. Can I do some sort of wildcard or further contains?

For example, based on the list and dataframe below, I'd like to return or filter to just row 0.

```
list = ["123 ABC", "456 DEF", "789 GHI"]

id    idlist
0      ABC    
1      XYZ
```

Something like

```
df_2 = df[df["idlist"].isin(list)]
```

would not work because it would be searching for an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more complicated string matching problem than usual, but you can use a list comprehension for performance:

```
lst = ["123 ABC", "456 DEF", "789 GHI"]
df['match'] = [any(x in l for l in lst) for x in df['idlist']]
df

   id idlist  match
0   0    ABC   True
1   1    XYZ  False
```

To simply filter, use

```
df[[any(x in l for l in lst) for x in df['idlist']]]

   id idlist
0   0    ABC
```

List comprehensions are my to-go syntax for many string operations. I've written a detailed writeup about their advantages in [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care).

If you need to handle NaNs, use a function with try-catch handling.

```
def search(x, lst):
    try:
        return any(x in l for l in lst)
    except TypeError:
        return False

df[[search(x, lst) for x in df['idlist']]]

   id idlist
0   0    ABC
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator library to check if the string is partly inlcuded:

```
import operator
operator.contains('ABC','123 ABC')
```