# Filter if a column contains sections the character in an external list

Tags: r, filtering, tidyverse

I have a df with hundred of rows and ca.100 columns, and an external list of more than 100 names. The names in the list are IUPAC names of chemicals (eg. 1,2-Cyclohexane dicarboxylic acid diisononyl ester), and in the main df one column matches the names in the list, even is only partially.

```r
#dummy_df

a <- c("1,2-Cyclohexane dicarboxylic acid diisononyl ester", "Diisodecyl phthalate", "Mono-hydroxy-isononyl phthalate (OH-MiNP)",
       "Mono-isononyl phthalate (MiNP)","Bisphenol A (BPA)","4,4'-(propane-2,2-diyl)diphenol (BPA)")
b <- c(1:6)
c <- c("mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l")
df <- data.frame(a,b,c, row.names = NULL)
colnames(df) <- c("ch.name", "quantity", "unit")

#external list of ch.names
IUPAC_list <- c("Cyclohegane oxylic acid", "Diisodecyl phthalate", "MiNP", 
            "BPA free uncogjugated (Bisphenol A uncoju)")
```

[image: View(df)]

I need to be able to subset df using the external list. The issue is that df$ch.name contains sometimes only part of the whole ch.name in the list or vice versa. I want to be able to basically say:

"If a row in df$ch.name **matches partially** the names in the IUPAC_list then pull it, otherwise remove row."

```r
#problem
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- df %>% filter(ch.name %in% IUPAC_list)
```

[image: View(new_df)]

df_new contains only "Diisodecyl phthalate" because matches perfectly
however, I need df_new to contain also the ch.vaules that are only partially matching such as "Bisphenol A" and "MiNP". While "Cyclohexane oxylic acid" will not be part of df_new since is not part of df in the first place.

```r
df_new2 <- df[grepl(paste(IUPAC_list, collapse = "|"), df$ch.name),]
```

[image: View(df_new2)]

Apparently does the trick, but is not good enough, it seems to match the chemicals only if they start with a string and does not search for matches in more complex names such as BPA free unconjugated (Bisphenol A uncoju). Also MiNP and ox-MiNP are present in df_new2 however they are different chemicals.

The ideal output should look like [image: this].

I am surely missing a simple solution that I am not finding.
My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245450/filter-dataframe-if-column-is-in-any-part-of-list), however, I am trying it in R.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you give the output that you want?

Comment: @VitaminB16 , I edited the question to show outputs and desired output.

Comment: I am sure there must be similar question on `r` also