# Loop through rows and assign value based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have dates for each row in my dataframe and want to assign a value to a new column based on a condition of the date.

Normally if I assign a value to a new column, I would do something like this:

```
def get_mean(df):
   return df.assign(
     grouped_mean = lambda df: df.groupby('group')['X']
       .transform(lambda df: df.mean())
   )
```

No I am looking for a solution like that, since the solution I have now is very slow and not beautiful.

Is there a better way than my current solution and use assign?

I currently came up with this solution:

```
def set_season(df):
    df = df.copy()
    for i in df.index:
        if (df.loc[i, 'Date'] >= pd.Timestamp('2008-08-30')) & (df.loc[i, 'Date'] <= pd.Timestamp('2009-05-31')):
            df.at[i, 'season'] = '08-09'
        elif  (df.loc[i, 'Date'] >= pd.Timestamp('2009-08-22')) & (df.loc[i, 'Date'] <= pd.Timestamp('2010-05-16')):
            df.at[i, 'season'] = '09-10'
        elif  (df.loc[i, 'Date'] >= pd.Timestamp('2010-08-28')) & (df.loc[i, 'Date'] <= pd.Timestamp('2011-05-22')):
            df.at[i, 'season'] = '10-11'

    return df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas and in most cases in Python general, we want to avoid *looping over our data* because it can be slower up to factors 1000x. Pandas and numpy provide lot of vectorized solutions, for most of our problem cases. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

In your case we can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which lets us define *multiple conditions* and based on those conditions we define *choices*.

Plus we can make your code more elegant by using [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with the `inclusive=True` argument.

```
conditions = [
    df['Date'].between('2008-08-30', '2009-05-31', inclusive=True),
    df['Date'].between('2009-08-22', '2010-05-16', inclusive=True),
    df['Date'].between('2010-08-28', '2011-05-22', inclusive=True)
]

choices = ['08-09', '09-10', '10-11']

df['season'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='99-99')
```

---

**Sidenote**

We can also rewrite your first function better with removing the two `lambda` functions and simply assigning the new column with `groupby` and `transform` and also taking extra arguments: `group` & `mean_col`

```
def get_mean(df, group, mean_col):

    df['mean'] = df.groupby(group)[mean_col].transform('mean')

    return df
```

**Example**

```
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['Banana', 'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple'],
                   'Weight':[10, 12, 8, 9, 14]})

        Fruit  Weight
0      Banana      10
1  Strawberry      12
2       Apple       8
3      Banana       9
4       Apple      14

get_mean(df, 'Fruit', 'Weight')

        Fruit  Weight  mean
0      Banana      10   9.5
1  Strawberry      12  12.0
2       Apple       8  11.0
3      Banana       9   9.5
4       Apple      14  11.0
```

Comment: beat me to it - `select` is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: @Erfan. This is great for True cases, how about the 'False' cases. For eg, if it not between the first condition? Do we need to define a separate condition and choices for them? or is there a work around like np.where where you can provide choices for true and False conditions?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.apply()` method, if the new column `'season'` depends only on one column:

```
def your_function(date):
    """
    takes a date a returns a string season
    """
    # code your function here

df['season'] = df['Date'].apply(your_function)
```

if your new column `'season'` depends on multiple other columns, use `axis = 1`:

```
def your_function(row):
    """
    takes a row from your dataframe and returns a result
    """
    # code your function here
    # example if you want a sum of col1, col2, col3
    return row['col1'] + row['col2'] + row['col3']

df['season'] = df.apply(your_function, axis = 1)
```