# pandas: Apply operation to all columns without applymap?

Tags: pandas

I’m trying to figure out if it’s possible to achieve the following without using apply and without using a for loop.

```
df= [df[x].map(lambda x: len(x) > 5) for x in df.columns]
```

I’m specifically trying to avoid apply and applymap, and look for a vectorised solution. All values in DF are strings. I’m using the above as a mask later on.

The fastest I've found is:

```
df1 = [df[x].map(lambda x: len(x) > 5) for x in df.columns]
df2 = df[pd.concat(df1, axis=1, keys=[s.name for s in df1]).any(1)]
```

It's faster than:

```
df[(df.applymap(len) > 5).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? And can you add some example data for us so we can reproduce an answer?

Comment: `df(df.applymap(len) > 5).any(axis=1)]` is actually not a bad solution. Strings are inherently not vectorizable so these solutions are all comparable. Another one is `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len() > 5)` which applies the comparison column-wise.

Comment: @cs95 I’m getting significant speed improvements with without applymap and apply, that’s why I asked.

Comment: @cs95 - I've added some examples that I've tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `vectorize`, at least it should be slightly faster than `apply` , about the comparision of for loop , it all depends on your data size and shape . [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

```
np.vectorize(len)(df.values)>5
```

Comment: @zerohedge that is as I mentioned , it depends on your real df size :-)

Comment: `df[np.vectorize(len)(df.values)>5]` is returning the first row for all rows in `df`, how can I use it for my purposes?

Comment: this seems to expand each row to multiple rows (per column), I need an any check that only returns the the row (and only one per row) for every row where the condition is met.

Comment: @zerohedge you can add np.any():-)

Comment: where do I put that though? The problem is that's expanding each row to multiple row, per column. For now I'm using `df1 = a[np.vectorize(len)(a.values) > 5]
    df2 = df1.groupby(df1.index).first()`

Comment: @zerohedge in your case `np.all(np.vectorize(len)(df.values)>5,1)`