# Merge two dataframes on a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, merge

I have a two dataframes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,[4,5]],[6,7,8,[9,10]]], columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4,'abc'],[5,'ef'], [10,'g'], [12,'hijk']], columns=['a_2','b_2'])

In [151]: df
Out[151]: 
   a  b  c        d
0  1  2  3   [4, 5]
1  6  7  8  [9, 10]

In [152]: df2
Out[152]: 
   a_2   b_2
0    4   abc
1    5    ef
2   10     g
3   12  hijk
```

I want to merge the two based on column 'd' of df and get the following output-

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,[4,5],['abc','ef']],[6,7,8,[9,10],['g']]], columns=['a','b','c','d','b_2'])


In [153]: df3
Out[153]: 
   a  b  c        d        b_2
0  1  2  3   [4, 5]  [abc, ef]
1  6  7  8  [9, 10]        [g]
```

I did try with 'merge' but I am not getting the required results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly a merge problem, but I'd do this using a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that calls [**`Series.get`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html):

```
s = df2.set_index('a_2')['b_2']  # mapping to use
[[s.get(y) for y in x if y in s] for x in df['d']]
# [['abc', 'ef'], ['g']]
```

```
# df['b_2'] = [[s.get(y) for y in x if y in s] for x in df['d']]
df3 = df.assign(b_2=[[s.get(y) for y in x if y in s] for x in df['d']])
df3

   a  b  c        d        b_2
0  1  2  3   [4, 5]  [abc, ef]
1  6  7  8  [9, 10]        [g]
```

[Evidence suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care) that list comprehensions should be reasonably fast given the non-vectorizable nature of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
col1=df1.apply(lambda ss:df2.query("a_2 in @ss.d").b_2.tolist(),1)
df1.assign(b_2=col1)

：

┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ index │   a   │   b   │   c   │    d    │    b_2    │
│ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │ int32[] │ varchar[] │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼─────────┼───────────┤
│     0 │     1 │     2 │     3 │ [4, 5]  │ [abc, ef] │
│     1 │     6 │     7 │     8 │ [9, 10] │ [g]       │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(pd.merge(
    df.explode('d').reset_index(),
    df2,left_on='d',
    right_on='a_2',
    how = 'left'
    )
.groupby(['index',*list('abc')])[['d','b_2']].agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist())
.reset_index()
.drop('index',axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c        d        b_2
0  1  2  3   [4, 5]  [abc, ef]
1  6  7  8  [9, 10]        [g]
```