# Perfplot bench() raises "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the input types"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, perfplot

I am using [perpflot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) library to test the effect of `DatetimeIndex` on searching for a pandas dataframe.

I have defined a setup function to cretate 2 dataframes. One with datetime index and other with time as a column. I have also defined 2 functions which uses `.loc` in index and on column respectively and returns the subdata. However, it shows me a `typeError`.

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import perfplot


def setup_code(n):
    timeline = pd.date_range(end=datetime.now(), freq='1s', periods=n)
    sensor_readings = np.random.randint(100, size=(n, 4))
    col_labels = ['Sensor1', 'Sensor2', 'Sensor3', 'Sensor4']
    data = pd.DataFrame(sensor_readings, columns=col_labels)
    data['time'] = timeline
    data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
    data2 = data.copy()
    data2 = data2.set_index('time')
    print(n)
    return [data, data2]


def f1(ldata):
    data = ldata[0]
    subdata = data.loc[(data['time'] >= '2019-06-21 08:00:00') & (data['time'] <= '2019-06-21 11:00:00')]
    return subdata


def f2(ldata):
    data = ldata[1]
    subdata = data.loc['2019-06-21 04:00:00':'2019-06-21 10:00:00']
    return subdata


out = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup_code,  
    kernels=[
        f1, f2
    ],
    n_range=[1000 ** k for k in range(1, 3)],
    labels=['Without Indexing', 'With Indexing'],
    xlabel='Length of DataFrame'
)
out.show()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  File ".\scratchpad.py", line 39, in <module>
    xlabel='Length of DataFrame'
  File "C:\Users\hpandya\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\perfplot\main.py", line 128, in bench
    reference, kernel(data)
  File "C:\Users\hpandya\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2423, in allclose
    res = all(isclose(a, b, rtol=rtol, atol=atol, equal_nan=equal_nan))
  File "C:\Users\hpandya\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2521, in isclose
    xfin = isfinite(x)
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

It is weird that it is showing error on the line where I have defined the `xlabel`. I fee like I am missing something trivial here.

Comment: I don't have perfplot installed to test, but you mentioned using a datetime object. I think those are stored using integers for which you won't be able to use the `isfinite` function which is designed to work with doubles.

Comment: Based on the traceback it looks like perfplot is calling `isfinite` on line 128 of `main.py` in the `bench` function.

Comment: @user545424, this is very weird. If I change the return statements from `return subdata` to `return True`, it does not show me the error. I do not understand why the library does a check on the function return elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bench()` and `show()` methods by default compare the kernel outputs to ensure that all the methods produce the same output (for correctness). The check is done using numpy functions which may not apply to all cases or all kernel outputs.

What you want to do is specify an `equality_check` argument, which allows some flexibility in how the output is compared. This is especially useful when comparing things such as iterables of strings or dictionaries, which `numpy` cannot handle well.

Set `equality_check` to None if you're confident your functions are correct, or otherwise pass some callable which implements your own checking logic.

```
out = perfplot.bench(
    ...
    equality_check=lambda x, y: x.equals(y)  # equality_check=None
)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028200/4909087) (scroll to the bottom) for more examples of how `equality_check` has been used for timing different functions.

Comment: seems like `equality_check=None` takes `setup` time into consideration along with the function. For my example, it shows that indexing the time affects the searching negatively. Also `equality_check=lambda x, y: x.equals(y)` will fail because one dataframe will have `time` column and other will have time as index.

Comment: @harvpan To my knowledge, the equality check isn't a part of the timing. Re: your second point, you can always do `lambda x, y: x.reset_index().equals(y)` to reset the index as a column before checking.