# Vectorizing Pairwise Column Element-wise Product in NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-algebra, array-broadcasting

I have two DataFrames:

```
>>> d1

    A  B
0   4  3
1   5  2
2   4  3

>>> d2

    C  D  E
0   1  4  7
1   2  5  8
2   3  6  9

>>> what_I_want

    AC  AD  AE  BC  BD  BE
0   4   16  28  3   12  21
1   10  25  40  4   10  16
2   12  24  36  9   18  27
```

Two DataFrames have the same number of rows (say m), but different number of columns (say ncol_1, ncol_2). The output is a m by (ncol_1 * ncol_2) DataFrame. Each column is the product of the one column in d1 and one column in d2.

I have come across `np.kron` but it does not do quite what I want. My actual data has millions of rows.

I am wondering if there is any vectorized way of doing this? I currently have a `itertools.product` implementation but the speed is excruciatingly slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One with [`NumPy-broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
a = d1.to_numpy(copy=False) # d1.values on older pandas versions
b = d2.to_numpy(copy=False)
df_out = pd.DataFrame((a[:,:,None]*b[:,None,:]).reshape(len(a),-1))
df_out.columns = [i+j for i in d1.columns for j in d2.columns]
```

For large data, leverage `multi-cores` with `numexpr` -

```
import numexpr as ne

out = ne.evaluate('a3D*b3D',{'a3D':a[:,:,None],'b3D':b[:,None]}).reshape(len(a),-1)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works like a charm. But I have a question: is there a reason in NumPy version, you are using ```b[:,None,:]``` but in numexpr you are using  ```b[:,None]```?

Comment: @KemengZhang Nah, it's the same. In the numexpr version, I was trying to make it compact to keep it within the answer post allowed width.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, using for loop is not always bad, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care)

```
pd.DataFrame({x+y: df1[x]*df2[y]  for x in df1 for y in df2})
Out[81]: 
   AC  AD  AE  BC  BD  BE
0   4  16  28   3  12  21
1  10  25  40   4  10  16
2  12  24  36   9  18  27
```