# Duplicates when appending string to list from dataframe with common column value

Tags: python, pandas

Beginner here, I am trying to isolate the names of neighborhoods from a dataframe of Toronto based on a cluster value I've assigned them. Instead of a list of 3 unique items, I end up with a list 2363 items long.

```
Neigh_List = []
for n in toronto_merged['Cluster Labels']:

        if n == 7 :
        x = toronto_merged['Neighborhood']
        Neigh_List.append(x) if x not in Neigh_List else None      


        
               
Neigh_List

[0                                                                                                Parkwoods
 1                                                                                                Parkwoods
 2                                                                                         Victoria Village
 3                                                                                         Victoria Village
 4                                                                                         Victoria Village
                                                        ...                                                
 2359    Mimico NW , The Queensway West , South of Bloor , Kingsway Park South West , Royal York South West
 2360    Mimico NW , The Queensway West , South of Bloor , Kingsway Park South West , Royal York South West
 2361    Mimico NW , The Queensway West , South of Bloor , Kingsway Park South West , Royal York South West
 2362    Mimico NW , The Queensway West , South of Bloor , Kingsway Park South West , Royal York South West
 2363    Mimico NW , The Queensway West , South of Bloor , Kingsway Park South West , Royal York South West
 Name: Neighborhood, Length: 2364, dtype: object]
```

Comment: Using the advice (which I ran into but wasn't understanding until it was applied here) my code looks like this. Thank you!                                                                                                       neigh_list = set()
for a in toronto_merged['Cluster Labels']:
    if a == 7:    
        for a in toronto_merged['Neighborhood']:
    
            neigh_list.add(x)
neigh_list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, looping over Pandas dataframes should be avoided for larger datasets (~1000+) as Pandas built-in vectorized functions are often faster ([See this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care)).

You could try something like:

```
neigh_list = list(toronto_merged.loc[toronto_merged['Neighborhood'] == 7]]['Neighborhood'].unique())
```

Additionally, if you want to avoid duplicates in a list, you could use python [sets (see 5.4 at the time of writing)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
unique_elements = set()
for x in some_iterable:
    unique_elements.add(x)
```

Or, using a set comprehension:

```
unique_elements = {unique_item for unique_item in some_iterable}
```

Comment: Yes you were just ahead of me :) (and I sneakily made some edits/corrected some mistakes after having posted as well). Quite amazing (in a good way) that it's often harder to be the first to answer than to have your own questions answered.

Comment: You went an extra mile though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Pandas’ own power. Select all rows where Cluster Label equals 7, get the unique Neighborhoods?

```py
...
Neigh_List = toronto_merged.loc[lambda d: d['Cluster Labels'].eq(7)]['Neighborhood'].unique().tolist()

# instead of .unique(), you can also do .drop_duplicates() which is faster
```