# Is there a more efficient way to loop through a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, vba, numpy, loops

I have a very simple excel spreadsheet with a table that goes something like this:

| cash | Margin |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.45 |
| =if(B2>0.5, A2, 1) | =if(A3>0.2,1,0) |

Some cells calling other cells on the same rows or on previous rows.
The idea is to generate a table like this a few hundred of thousands of times with diff inputs/params.

I did that first using VBA with arrays. Setting the first-row value and then looping through the rest which takes quite long. With a bit of optimization, I ran the simulation in 3 hours.

I then moved on to python using pandas thinking it would be much faster.
But again, because of the dependency between one cell and the cell above I have to use for loops. A simple df['margin']=df['blah']*margin_rate does not work.

My code therefore looks something like this:

```
df.loc[0, 'cash collateral'] = 0
df.loc[0, 'release'] = 1 if df.loc[0, 'LTV'] > max_value else 0
...
for i in range(1, len(df)):
   if df.loc[i-1, 'call'] == 1:
      df.loc[i, 'release'] =  df.loc[i-1, 'release']
   ...
```

It works! But it's hardly faster than VBA. Do you know how I could fasten it up? Maybe some recursive functions, or using NumPy over pandas?

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: You **should never iterate** in pandas...!!! Check answer from cs95 in the thread: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: @Wizhi As a counterpoint to the "never iterate", just because it's a really great and informative read: [Are for-loops in pandas really bad? When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care)