# How to create a list from Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this. I am trying to create a list of Names. For ex: `["Mike", "Jean"]`:

```
0. Mike, Jean
1. May, Weather
2. Jack, 100
```

What I've tried:

```
df["NAME"] = df["NAME"].str.split(",")
for i in range(len(df["NAME"])):
    df["NAME"][i] = df["NAME"][i] .split(",")
```

*OUTPUT*

```
0. [Mike, Jean]
1. [May, Weather]
2. [Jack, 100]
```

*OUTPUT I WANT*

```
0. ["Mike", "Jean"]
1. ["May", "Weather"]
2. ["Jack", "100"]
```

I am new to Python and Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mike, Jean', 'May, Weather', 'Jack, 100']})
```

When you run:

```
df['Name'].str.split(', ')
```

and get:

```
0      [Mike, Jean]
1    [May, Weather]
2       [Jack, 100]
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

The `[Mike, Jean]` format is **just a representation**.

The real data is indeed a Series of lists, as show by an explicit conversion of the Series to list:

```
df['Name'].str.split(', ').to_list()
```

output:

```
[['Mike', 'Jean'],
 ['May', 'Weather'],
 ['Jack', '100']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the values of your dataframe and easily convert the rows of the resulting Numpy array into lists (cf example code below)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Name'] = ['Name1', 'Name2']
df['FirstName'] = ['FirstName1', 'FirstName2']

L = []
for row in df.values:
    L.append(list(row))
    
print(L)
```

Cheers

Comment: Looping through dataframe's row is discouraged unless strictly necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use a for-loop, you can do the split with:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split()
```

This will return a pandas series containing a list per row, such as:

```
0 ["Mike", "Jean"]
1 ["May", "Weather"]
2 ["Jack", "100"]
```

If you wish to extract the Series' values as list itself then you can use:

```
name_lists = df['Name'].str.split().values.tolist()
```

Returning:

```
[["Mike","Jean"],["May","Weather"],["Jack","100"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet below should solve your purpose :)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["[Mike, Jean]" , "[May, Weather]", "[Jack, 100]"], columns=['name'])

df.head()
```

```
             name
0    [Mike, Jean]
1  [May, Weather]
2     [Jack, 100]
```

```py
df['type_name']  = df.apply(lambda y: type(y['name']), axis=1)

df['name1'] = df.apply(lambda y: y['name'].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(", "), axis=1)

df['type_name1']  = df.apply(lambda y: type(y['name1']), axis=1)

df.head()
```

```
             name      type_name           name1      type_name1
0    [Mike, Jean]  <class 'str'>    [Mike, Jean]  <class 'list'>
1  [May, Weather]  <class 'str'>  [May, Weather]  <class 'list'>
2     [Jack, 100]  <class 'str'>     [Jack, 100]  <class 'list'>
```

```py
final_list = df['name1'].values.tolist()

print(final_list)
```

```
[['Mike', 'Jean'], ['May', 'Weather'], ['Jack', '100']]
```